# List of list if statement for Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like:

```
[['a', 'b', 'null', 'c'], ['d', 'e', '5', 'f'], ['g' ,'h', 'null' ,'I'] ]
```

I want to uppercase all strings, but when I try:

```
x = 0
for row in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    listx.append(sheet.cell(row, x))
    [x.upper() for x in x in listx]
x += 1
```

I got:

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

How can I make a statement for it?

Comment: `... for x in x in listx` - that doesn't look right, surely?

Comment: Thanks for reply I tried make upper for each element in each lists and u are right that loop doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list comprehension does it, and retains your list of lists structure:

```
listx = [['a', 'b', 'null', 'c'], ['d', 'e', '5', 'f'], ['g' ,'h', 'null' ,'I'] ]

[[x.upper() for x in sublist] for sublist in listx]
```

returns:

```
[['A', 'B', 'NULL', 'C'], ['D', 'E', '5', 'F'], ['G', 'H', 'NULL', 'I']]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I tried sth look like code but when I run it I get TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable error

Comment: You are absolutely right I solved my problem with using pandas thanks for ur time.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for:

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'null', 'c'], ['d', 'e', '5', 'f'], ['g' ,'h', 'null' ,'I']]
new_list = []
for row in l:
    new_list.append([x.upper() for x in row])
```

Comment: solution by @sacul is better than this.